# LCARS, LaTeX and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I have created the following:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

% To set the font and formatting:

\setmainfont{[lcars.ttf]} %To load the font named lcars
%\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold=1.5, AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{lcars.ttf} % To set bold or italics if I wanted to.

% LCARS Colours begin:

% Sources for colours:
% http://lcarsmania.com/designguide/Okudagrams_Color.png 
% http://www.lcarscom.net/lcars_colors.gif 

\definecolor{LCARSBG}{HTML}{000000} % Pure black
\definecolor{LCARSTCMain}{HTML}{FF9900} %Dark yellow
\definecolor{LCARSTC1}{HTML}{CC99CC} % Light purple
\definecolor{LCARSTC2}{HTML}{9999CC} % Light blue
\definecolor{LCARSTC3}{HTML}{CC6666} % Light red 
\definecolor{LCARSTC4}{HTML}{FFCC99} % Light peach 
\definecolor{LCARSTC5}{HTML}{9999FF} % Light blue, a different variant
\definecolor{LCARSTC6}{HTML}{FF9966} % Light orange
\definecolor{LCARSTC7}{HTML}{CC6699} % Pink
\definecolor{LCARSTC8}{HTML}{F5173C} % Light red 
% LCARS Colours end.

% To set page numbers to the right colour and style.

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{LCARSTCMain}{\thepage}}% Page # in middle/centre of footer
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\pagecolor{LCARSBG} % Page background colour.
\color{LCARSTCMain} % Main body text colour.

\section*{\textcolor{LCARSTC5}{Section Title:}}

\textcolor{LCARSTC8}{A question or subheading here?}\newline

\textcolor{LCARSTC6}{Another sub heading:}\newline

\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

However I want to do the actual shapes I believe tikz package is best for this?

Looking at : http://www.lcars-terminal.de/tutorial/guideline.htm

and especially http://www.lcars-terminal.de/tutorial/guideline/font_size.gif

I want to add the shapes like in this image to the margins and header of the document, what is the best way to achieve this? I am beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: Just to let you know that I cannot compile your document on my machine. It is very possible that this is my fault because I may not have some necessary ingredient like a font installed. However, it seems that your question is not centered around these fonts, but is about some shapes that you wish to create. So in order to have more users looking at your question, you may want to provide instead a document that is easy to compile, and illustrates what you have tried.

Comment: Apologies I thought it was obvious which font parts to delete, additionally I presumed I would get an answer like the one below anyway. The document was not really that relevant more the attempt at drawing the shape. Apologies...

Comment: No worries! I was just trying to explain how you can attract more attention to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{LCARSTC2}{HTML}{9999CC} % Light blue
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[LCAR/.style={rounded corners,path picture={
\fill[LCARSTC2,even odd rule,rounded corners] (path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east)
([xshift=1mm,yshift=2mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-2mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
},inner ysep=4mm,inner xsep=2mm,font=\sffamily}]
\node [LCAR] {Hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment (note that I only load geometry to use `showframe` to mark the boundaries of the page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{LCARSTC2}{HTML}{9999CC} % Light blue
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[LCAR/.style={rounded corners,path picture={
\fill[LCARSTC2,even odd rule,rounded corners] (path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east)
([xshift=1mm,yshift=2mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-2mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
},inner ysep=4mm,inner xsep=2mm,font=\sffamily}]
\node [LCAR,text width=\linewidth-6mm,minimum width=\linewidth] {\lipsum[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that there are many more options and keys, and even possibilities (you may use e.g. the `tikzmark` library), but I have the same problem as Fermat: I do not have enough space to spell out the details. ;-)

Comment: How do I set this box to the page width?

Comment: Can you please elaborate,  I tried to add in the code as follows but it did not work: `\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum width=\linewidth,LCAR/.style={rounded corners,path picture={
\fill[LCARSTC2,even odd rule,rounded corners] (path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east)
([xshift=1mm,yshift=2mm]path picture bounding box.south west)
rectangle ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-2mm]path picture bounding box.north east);
},inner ysep=4mm,inner xsep=2mm}]
\node [LCAR] {\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: This still does not work for me.

Comment: Yeah it compiles, no errors.  When I use lipsum it still goes off page with your code rather than hello world.

Comment: @SomeT If that is your main application, you may post another question of how to achieve this with `tcolorbox`. You might take my lower example as a basis for an MWE. `tcolorbox` takes care of all these things like `\noindent`, `text width` and so on. If Christian Hupfer is around, I am pretty sure you will get an excellent answer.

Comment: Feel free to extend on the current answer anyone in tcolorbox.

Comment: @SomeT Please ask a new question. I feel that this answers the original question. Asking questions is free, and if you ask a new question it will be seen by more users, and also help others.